# Error in php code "Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string"

Tags: php, xml

Bellow code showing "Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string". How can i solve this issue.

```
$rs=$_SESSION['hotelavail_rs'];
// I have stored xml response in a session.
// xml response should be string type.
$str=(string)$rs;

$DOC = new DOMDocument();
$xml =new SimpleXMLElement($str);
$DOC->loadXML($str);
$Data = Parse($DOC->firstChild);
```

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand what are you doing. Why you use 2 different php extensions (SOMSocument and SimpleXML) in parallel here? Btw, $DOC->firstChild has [DOMNode type](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.firstchild)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the docs for DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php), you call `saveXML()` to dump the XML to a string.

I'm assuming the error is occurring on this line?

```
$str=(string)$rs;
```

In which case you should change it to,

```
$str = $rs->saveXML();
```

But since you seem to be loading it all back into a DOMDocument anyway, why not just do this?

```
$rs = $_SESSION['hotelavail_rs'];
$Data = Parse($rs->firstChild);
```

If the error is occurring later (In the `Parse` function for example) then a different solution will be required. It would be helpful to know the exact line on which the error is being thrown.

*Note: None of the above is tested, I'm just going on what the docs say.*

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 *potential* problems. I say potential because I don't know what line the error is caused by.

- Are you sure that the XML is saved as a string in the session? You may want to try `var_dump($_SESSION['hotelavail_rs']);` and make sure that it's a string and not a DOMDocument object. If it's not a string, that would cause a problem with the `$str=(string)$rs;` line.
- The other potential problem is the `Parse()` function. Is it expecting a `DOMNode` or a string? If it's expecting a string, that won't work as `DOMDocument::firstNode` returns a `DOMNode` object. Unfortunately, `DOMDocument` doesn't have a way to return a particular node and child nodes as a string.

Comment: I have saved xml response in an array

Comment: @Hearaman - But how did you save it in the array? As a string or did you save it as a `DOMDocument` object? Can you show me the line of code you're using to save the XML in the array? And by array do you mean the `$_SESSION` array?

Comment: $res contains this curl response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611477/how-to-display-values-in-curl-xml-response-using-php

Comment: @Hearaman - The other problem is that we don't really know which one of those lines is causing you a problem. It may not be the way it's store. It could be the `Parse` function as I pointed on above. If that function expects a string, it won't work because `$DOC->firstNode` returns a DOMNode, not a `string`.

Comment: using this code  $xa=new xmlParser();
$xmlf=$xa->xml2array($res);
$xmla=($xmlf["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"]["ns1:OTA_HotelAvailRQResponse"]["OTA_HotelAvailRQReturn"]);
$_SESSION['hotelavail_rs']=$xmla;. Now $xmla is an array

Comment: @Hearaman - Well, that's part of your problem. The XML is no longer XML, it's an array. When you do `$str=(string)$rs;`, the value of `$str` most likely is `Array` (I mean the word Array, not that it's an array). To be honest, I don't see where you would get the error in the title of question in the code you've posted above. If you want to save the XML in the session, just do `$_SESSION['hotelavail_rs'] = $res` so that the actual string is passed. To solve the "DOMDocument cannot be convert as a string" error, you'll need to tell us what line the error is happening on and post the code for it.

Comment: This is one more error "DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1".                $DOC->loadXML($str); throwing this error.

Comment: @Hearaman - That's because `$str` doesn't contain XML. You should add an `echo htmlentities($str);` above that line and see what it is outputted. Make sure that `$str` is a string containing valid XML.

Comment: It has XML content. But there are no < and > brackets(In view source also).

Comment: @Hearaman - For DOMDocument to be able to import the string, it needs to be valid XML which would include many < and > characters that they're using to incapsulate tags. Wherever you're setting the value of `$str` originally, make sure it's valid XML.